# JSON-serializing non-string dictionary keys

Tags: python, json

I know I can do:

```
import datetime

def default(o):
    if type(o) is datetime.datetime:
        return o.isoformat()

data = {'a': datetime.datetime.today()}
json.dumps(data, default=default)
# '{"a": "2015-01-22T01:04:23.121392"}'
```

That works perfect. Now what if I have datetimes as my keys:

```
data = {datetime.datetime.today(): 'a'}
```

If I try the same it fails with a:

```
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

Is there any way I can do something similar, i.e. a custom converter but for keys?

Note: This is just a simple example. I have a deep nested dict structure where some keys are not strings.

EDIT: A nested example, but note that I don't have control over the data structure, it comes from an external function:

```
data = {'a': {datetime.datetime.today(): '1'}}
```

Comment: Why Python version are you using?

Comment: Do you have an existing structure with nested `datetime` objects? I'd suggest fixing it before you nest them, otherwise you'll have to recursively traverse the dict.

Comment: @s16h, 2.7 but a 3.4 solution would be ok.

Comment: `pickle.dumps` like one of the answers says, otherwise recursion and `repr` or `str`

Comment: @user3467349, unfortunately the structure comes from an external function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this:

```
class DatesToStrings(json.JSONEncoder):
    def _encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            def transform_date(o):
                return self._encode(o.isoformat() if isinstance(o, datetime) else o)
            return {transform_date(k): transform_date(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
        else:
            return obj

    def encode(self, obj):
        return super(DatesToStrings, self).encode(self._encode(obj))

>>> json.dumps({"a": {datetime.now(): 3}}, cls=DatesToStrings)
'{"a": {"2015-01-22T11:49:25.910261": 3}}'
```

Comment: passing a `cls` to `json.dumps` is a neat idea but I'm not sure it will work. Specifically your example does not work for nested dicts.

Comment: Yep, doesn't work for `data = {'a': {datetime.today(): '1'}}`

Comment: That's strange, works fine for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: try this: `d= {'a': datetime.datetime.now(), 'b': {datetime.datetime.now(): datetime.datetime.now()}, datetime.datetime.now(): {'c': 'b'} }`

Comment: Oh, right. That's not a problem with the recursion, it's just that my solution only transforms dates in the keys, not the values. Will do another.

Comment: @AndrewMagee, This solution has potential, let me try. Actually can you revert the last edit? I only need keys not values.

Comment: If you just need keys and not values then the current version should still work.

Comment: Yes, I meant for simplicity of the code. I am trying to understand, is this recursive?

Comment: Yes, it's recursive, the `_encode` function calls itself. As does `JSONEncoder.encode`, presumably.

Comment: To be honest though in real life I would probably go with the solutions that modify the data structure up front and then call `json.dumps` with default settings. That way you can test if the data structure is modified correctly independently from the serialisation.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the recursive version - note that I won't guarantee it will be any faster than the pickled version:

```
def dictRecursiveFormat(d): 
        for key, val in list(d.items()):
            if isinstance(key, datetime.datetime): 
                val = d.pop(key)
                d[str(key)] = val 
            if isinstance(val, datetime.datetime) and isinstance(key, datetime.datetime): 
                d[str(key)] = str(val)
            elif isinstance(val, datetime.datetime):
                d[key] = str(val)
            if type(val) is dict: 
                dictRecursiveFormat(val)
```

example:

```
In [52]: d= {'a': datetime.datetime.now(), 'b': {datetime.datetime.now(): datetime.datetime.now()}}

In [53]: dictRecursiveFormat(d)

In [54]: d
Out[54]: 
{'a': '2015-01-21 19:33:52.293182',
 'b': {'2015-01-21 19:33:52.293240': '2015-01-21 19:33:52.293229'}}
```

Comment: Based on this I've written a slightly modified version which works for any non-string type objects:



`def dictRecursiveFormat(d):  
    newDict = {}  
    for key, val in d.items():  
        newVal = str(val) if type(val) is not dict else dictRecursiveFormat(val)  
        if not isinstance(key, str):  
            newDict[str(key)] = newVal  
    return newDict`

Answer (score 2):

Upon Andrew Magee's and add nested list/set support:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime


class DatesToStrings(json.JSONEncoder):
    def _encode(self, obj):
        def transform_date(o):
            return self._encode(o.isoformat() if isinstance(o, datetime) else o)
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            return {transform_date(k): transform_date(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
        elif isinstance(obj, list) or isinstance(obj, set):
            return [transform_date(l) for l in obj]
        else:
            return obj

    def encode(self, obj):
        return super(DatesToStrings, self).encode(self._encode(obj))


print(json.dumps({"a": datetime.now()}, cls=DatesToStrings))
print(json.dumps({datetime.now(): 1}, cls=DatesToStrings))
print(json.dumps({"a": {datetime.now(): 3}}, cls=DatesToStrings))
print(json.dumps({"a": [datetime.now()]}, cls=DatesToStrings))
print(json.dumps({"a": {1: [datetime.now()]}}, cls=DatesToStrings))
print(json.dumps({"a": [{1: [datetime.now()]}]}, cls=DatesToStrings))
print(json.dumps({"a": {datetime.now()}}, cls=DatesToStrings))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use str to change the type will be ok:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> type(datetime.datetime.today())
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> data = {str(datetime.datetime.today()): 'a'}
>>> data
{'2015-01-22 08:13:11.554000': 'a'}
>>> data = {repr(datetime.datetime.today()): 'a'}
>>> data
{'datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 22, 8, 15, 0, 551000)': 'a'}
>>> data = {'a': {datetime.datetime.today(): '1'}}
>>> data
{'a': {datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 22, 8, 32, 25, 175000): '1'}}
```

Comment: `repr` would be better than `str`

Comment: @Ashwin Hm, why? With `str` one can use `strptime` to convert the string back to a `datetime`. With `repr`, one has to either use `eval` (better make sure that the string is what you think it is!) or parse the string. Or is there a better way to get a `datetime` from its `repr`?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which was asking about how to serialize a dictionary that has datetime.datetime keys into JSON.

Comment: I know I can do this but this solution is not general enough for nested structures.

Comment: @Elian Why not post a nested example?

Comment: I will, but I don't have control on the structure of the generated data because it comes from another function. That is why I want something general.

Comment: @jme The reason why I say that is the `str` representation might not be present for all object types. `repr` is more general than `str`

Comment: @Elian Try using `repr(data)` and then do a json dumps if required. That way it works even for nested structures

Comment: @Ashwin, Sorry I don't get it, can you post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are serializing for your python program to read at a later time, use `pickle` module to do this. It will preserve custom classes and objects as long as the definitions are visible to the script/module that is going to deserialize it and use it.

You could do something like:

```
data = {datetime.datetime.today(): 'a'}

try:    
    import cPickle as pickle # Try it. It could be faster
except:
    import pickle # Regular pickle as a fallback

with open("c:/mypickle.DAT", "w") as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

If writing to physical disk is not what you want, especially for performance reasons, you can try to write to a file-like object, like [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html).

Comment: Just a comment, the OP said *This is just a simple example*. So I would not suggest helping fix the `json` program, we should go to the root.

Comment: @Elian if this *is* your problem then I can help you. What OS are you running?

Comment: Like Mac/Windows/Linux/Ubuntu

Comment: actually I have a solution that runs faster than pickle using `eval`, but I am not satisfied with the solution because the double conversion + the eval is too slow, I am using linux, unix.

Comment: Have you also tried cPickle instead of pickle? It is way faster.

Comment: @kartikg3 Not necessarily.

Comment: I think anything that uses the disk will be too slow for my purposes.

Comment: Well then you can always serialize to a file-like object instead of a file. Like StringIO

Comment: oh, I have just noticed that I need strictly JSON, so pickle wont do it. Still thanks for your answer.

Comment: Oh can you update the question with this detail then?

Comment: @Elian Then you can try recursion - I added an example  answer, but I really doubt it will be faster...

Comment: @kartikg3, it is in the title.

Comment: Oh right gotcha. Downfalls of answering on the mobile while taking the transit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to fix the keys, including keys in nested dictionaries, before passing it to the serializer.

```
def datetime_key_fix(o):
    if isinstance(o, dict):
        for key in o:
            o[key] = datetime_key_fix(o[key])
            if type(key) is datetime.datetime:
                o[key.isoformat()] = o[key]
                del o[key]
    return o


data = {datetime.datetime.today(): {datetime.datetime.today(): "a"}}
print json.dumps(datetime_key_fix(data))
```

Comment: If the data is structured differently, this will not always work. E.g. dicts nested in lists.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import datetime
import json

data = {1:{datetime.datetime.today(): 'a'}, 2:{datetime.datetime.today(): 'a'}}
dataString = repr(data)
dataString
#"{1: {datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 21, 16, 56, 15, 219567): 'a'}, 2: {datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 21, 16, 56, 15, 219567): 'a'}}"
dataDictionary = eval(dataString)
dataDictionary
#{1: {datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 21, 16, 56, 15, 219567): 'a'}, 2: {datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 21, 16, 56, 15, 219567): 'a'}}
datajsonString = json.dumps(dataString)
#'"{1: {datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 21, 16, 56, 15, 219567): \'a\'}, 2: {datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 21, 16, 56, 15, 219567): \'a\'}}"'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic example that will work with any data object that have a `__str__` / `str(foo)` method associated, converting keys or values recursivally:

```
class MyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        '''Default serialization for JSON of the specific objects used inside the dataclasses.'''
        return str(o)

    def dict_keys_to_str(self, o):
        import datetime
        if isinstance(o, dict):
            for key in list(o.keys()):
                o[key] = self.dict_keys_to_str(o[key])
                if key is not None and not isinstance(key, (str, int, float, bool)):
                    o.update({str(key): o.pop(key)})
        return o

    def encode(self, obj):
        return super().encode(self.dict_keys_to_str(obj))


# Call the conversion.
json_output = json.dumps(dictionary, cls=MyJSONEncoder)
```